# Time syncing vs high latency

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, timer

I'm doing an auction script and time syncing between visitors and the server is necessary (when will the auction end). Every time a user bids, auction end time is extended for a few seconds. My problem is that several users are complaining about their timers skipping (some seconds) and figured out that it is because of a high latency connection.

My current algorithm has a javascript function that runs every second, getting time left for the auction through ajax requests. Is there a better way to approach this, especially for high latency users, to prevent the timer skipping problem?

Comment: firing off more requests when dealing with high latency would probably just make things worse, especially if responses start coming back out-of-order. e.g. 12:08:10 comes back, but suddenly a long-delayed 12:08:03 pops up and resets the clock yet again.

Comment: @MarcB yes thats actually what's happening. What irks me is that time being synced is very vital for the auctions, thus requiring me to do such. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: do filtering on clock updates, don't allow backwards time movements. That's about all you can do.Other than tell your users to ditch their 300 baud AOL dialups and get something a little faster.

Comment: You may not want to implement this, but a good alternative for this type of communication would be Web Sockets.

Comment: Have you looked into long polling? Use you could use a jquery countdown clock and then just change the countdown time whenever a new bid is placed. Should cut your ajax calls drastically. I just implemented this for a chat room function.

Comment: @ianpgall ive looked at zeromq but that would force me to change most parts of the project so I am looking for alts

Comment: @Pitchinnate not yet, will do, thanks man! how are you doing this with your chatroom? do you use just ajax or websockets?

Comment: It uses ajax, but basically you let PHP run a loop and it doesn't send a response unless there is a new message posted or 25 seconds have passed. I looked into Sockets and node.js but didn't really like that option. Long Polling is actually how Facebook does their insite chat.

Comment: Have you tried the setTimeout technique listed on this site? http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery It will wait for a response before sending the next request.  The person will only get the amount of responses that his internet connection can handle, which unfortunately you can only slightly improve (long polling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Adaptive intervals

First of all, I would suggest that you decrease the amount of polling. I don't know about your server implementation, but the current setup will create a lot of requests once you have a couple of users.

I would suggest that you adjust the polling interval depending on how much time is left. If there are two hours left until the end of an auction, we might not really care if the additional seconds are only fetched from the server every minute, right? You could do it like this

```
pollingInterval = secondsLeft / 100
```

The interval is shorter and the result is more accurate towards the end of the auction.

#### Server Sent Events

For the last minute or so, when you want a high accuracy, regular polling at short intervals is not the best solution, as discussed in the comments. Long polling is an option, but you should also look into HTML5 [Server Sent Events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events), which is like a native browser implementation of long polling. There's a [good introduction and comparison to Websockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/). Browser support is already pretty good, [there's a polyfill](https://github.com/remy/polyfills/blob/master/EventSource.js) for unsupported browsers which falls back to...polling.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into long polling? Use you could use a jquery/javascript countdown clock and then just change the countdown time whenever a new bid is placed. Should cut your ajax calls drastically.

Answer (score 1):

> javascript function that runs every second

This the old way to do what you want.

I think you need to use web-sockets to ensure real-time delivery for all users.
If you want to save time you can use any web-socket servers available instead of making it yourself.

I prefer Real-Time Pusher
It's easy and you can use it free but with a limited number of users. Also you can upgrade for more users.
[www.pusher.com](http://www.pusher.com)

Also, have good API documentation to help you to implement what you want fast and easy.

For any help with Pusher-or-websockets feel free to ask.